# Make sublist look like first level list

Tags: lists, indentation, enumitem

I'm using a `wide` list of the `enumitem` package. Except for having a label at the beginning of each item, the items of the `wide` list look like ordinary text. I would like a list inside the `wide` list to look exactly as if it were at first level. However, it seems to inherit the changes due to the `wide` option of the parenting list. How can the default indentation values be restored? See a self-explanatory example below.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
Normal text. Now a `wide' list:
\begin{enumerate}[wide]
    \item This is a list for long text and therefore has no left margin.
    \begin{enumerate}[label=(\alph*)]
        \item This has a strange indentation\\
        It should be indented exactly like (*) below since to the reader it should look as if we were on the first list level, not the second.
    \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

And now a normal list:
\begin{enumerate}[label=(\alph*)]
    \item This (first level) list (*) is being referred to.\\
    New line of the same item.
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to do it. I think, however, a list inside a wide list should have its label aligned with the label of the wide, not with the label of a ‘general’ first level list, as the latter is slightly shifted to the left of a paragraph indent (~ 2.5-3pt), which doesn't lok too good, in my opinion. Demo:    \documentclass{scrartcl}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage{enumitem}

```
\begin{document}
Normal text. Now a `wide' list:
\begin{enumerate}[wide]
  \item This is a list for long text and therefore has no left margin. Text text text text text text text text text Text text text text text text text text text
        \begin{enumerate}[label=(\alph*), wide=0.95\parindent, leftmargin =2.8em]
          \item This item is aligned with the above first level item. \\
                It should be indented exactly like (*) below since to the reader it should look as if we were on the first list level, not the second.
        \end{enumerate}
  \item This is another item with long text. Text text text text text text text text text Text text text text text text text text text
        \begin{enumerate}[label=(\alph*),labelindent =0.3\parindent, align = right, leftmargin =2.5em , labelsep=! ]
          \item This one has a the normal indentation of a first level list. \\
                It is indented exactly like (*) below since to the reader it should look as if we were on the first list level, not the second.
        \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

And now a normal list:
\begin{enumerate}[label=(\alph*)]
  \item This (first level) list (*) is being referred to.\\
        New line of the same item.
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. But the two (a)'s still do not have the same distance from the left margin. Now, clearly I could play around with the numbers until it looks ok, but... is there a way to get it *exactly* right, i.e., to recover the default spacing?

Comment: The first (a) is *exactly* aligned with the `1` of the above level list. The ‘normal’ list is not well aligned: the distance to the left margin is not quite the value of `parindent`, as is the first list and its sublist. Perhaps in your preamble you should set normal lists as  the sublist, with the `\setlist` command.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand you correctly. The last list ("normal list") is the standard list when no parameter has been changed (except for the `label`). I asked how the second level list can be made to look exactly like the "normal list", which is obviously not the case here: Both the label and the item text are at a different spot.

Comment: @Deniz: I updated my answer to fully satisfy your requirement, but I still think ‘normal’ lists should have their indentation slightly modified. See my explanations.